# How to use &&, || together

Tags: javascript, arrays, operators

I have no idea why the following returns false.

```
var pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'bat'];
console.log(pets.includes(('cat' && 'monkey') || 'bat' ));
```

As 'bat' is in pet array, I thought this returns true.

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: What logic did you think you were expressing here? Because it's **not** *"if both cat and monkey are pets, or if bat is"*.

Comment: `includes()` accepts a single argument as a string. You will have to use `.includes()` for each string like `(pets.includes('cat') && pets.includes('monkey')) || pets.includes('bat')`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation. I understand. Sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `('cat' && 'monkey') || 'bat'` gives `monkey`. The reason it gives `monkey` is because `'cat' && 'monkey'` expression evaluates to `monkey` as both `cat` and `monkey` is defined and using `&&` for both defined values, it takes the second value, i.e `monkey`. And when `'monkey' || 'bat'` is evaluated it gives the first value `monkey` as in this case also both the values are defined but in `||` expression it gives the first defined value which is `monkey` in this case.

And here is the mystery solved,

```
pets.includes(('cat' && 'monkey') || 'bat');
//becomes
pets.includes('monkey'); //which is false
```

```js
var pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'bat'];
console.log(('cat' && 'monkey') || 'bat');
console.log(pets.includes(('cat' && 'monkey') || 'bat'));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `&&` and `||` were meant to compare boolean expressions. What you actually want to do is:

```
console.log((pets.includes('cat') && pets.includes('monkey')) || pets.includes('bat'));
```

Comment: Note that you have 4 `(` but 5 `)`, so this won't work. Also, when combining `&&` and `||`, I prefer to be explicit about grouping because precedence doesn't always guarantee the correct order. That could be personal preference though.

Comment: It's my personal preference but yeah, since this an answer for new programmers, it's probably better to make the grouping explicit.

Answer (score 0):

For a real check if `pets` contains two other values, you need a different approach and iterate the value with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and check a single value in the callback with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'bat'];

console.log(['cat', 'monkey'].every(animal => pets.includes(animal)))           // false
console.log(['cat', 'monkey'].every(animal => pets.includes(animal)) || 'bat'); // 'bat'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't know this approach. Very helpful, thank you again!